# How does the twitter website prevent white pages between page loads?

Tags: html, css, twitter

When I am using the twitter website https://twitter.com/ and click on the tabs on the top there does not appear to be any white page where the page is loading. If I click on a different tab I see a spinner in the middle top of the page then the new page appears instantly without a blank white page in-between.

How is this achieved? I should note I am using Google Chrome web browser.

Small update to this, I noticed white page in between my pages and was comparing it to twitters page load. Then I took out the modernizr javascript library then my page rendered fast just like twitter and I don't notice white page in-between. So I think, this question is really not a good question now as the reason I was seeing white page was the modernizr library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using AJAX, check it out

[AJAX Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))